# Mysql select with priority on a column in an OR-statement

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
page_id     script_name     page_name    title
-------------------------------------------------
1           projects.php    NULL         NULL
2           NULL            projects     Projects
```

I want to search for `projects` in the column `page_name`. If it doesn't exist I want to search for `projects.php` in the column `script_name`. Is there a way of doing this in one mysql query?

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM `pages`
WHERE `page_name` = 'projecten'
OR `script_name` = 'index.php'
```

And I want to give priority to the `page_name` search in de `OR` statement. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is rows with **page_name 'projects'** first then rows with **script_name 'index.php'**
try this

```
 select * from pages
 where page_name='projects'
 union 
 select * from pages
 where script_name='index.php'
```